# Disabling Identity-Aware Proxy is Breaking AppEngine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I enabled the Identity-Aware Proxy in the Google Cloud for some services running on the AppEngine and it seemed to work just fine.  However, when I now disable the IAP (there is a toggle switch to turn it off), I am now receiving the error:

*Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.*

When I try to access the service.

Comment: Did you wait a bit (10 minutes) and tried again?

Comment: Yes.  And I tried turning IAM back on and I'm no getting the same error.  This site contains API endpoints but I have another site that in the same project which hosts a website and I can access that without issue.

Comment: IAP is only a proxy. You shouldn't have issues, except if your API rely on metadata (headers) added by IAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the Security team for my company had implemented some new policies which were breaking the application.  Thus, it was not IAM that was the issue as was mentioned by some in the comments.